# Linux scope of redirection

Tags: gdb, redirect

I'm writing a script which starts gdb in xterm, and I would like to start my program with the output redirected to a file.

My command is something like this:

```
xterm -e gdb --args myprog --myargs > /tmp/file
```

How do I indicate which command the redirection applies to? It could apply to xterm, gdb, or myprog.

I tried using quotes:

```
xterm -e gdb --args "myprog --myargs > /tmp/file"
```

But then gdb tried to open a file with name "`myprog --myargs > /tmp/file`". Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a reasonably recent version of GDB, the following works:

```
gdb -q -ex 'set args foo > /tmp/foo.out' -ex run -ex quit /bin/echo
```